# Saving the highscore for a game?

Tags: python, save, pygame, leaderboard

I have made a very simple game in python using pygame. The score is based on whatever level the player reached. I have the level as a variable called `score`. I want to display the top level at the start or end of the game.

I would be even more happy to display more than one score, but all of the other threads I have seen were too complicated for me to understand, so please keep it simple: I'm a beginner, only one score is necessary.

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: what is your problem? what keeps you from doing `print(score)`?

Comment: 2.7.4 and my problem is that i want to be able to display the score again after the program has been closed

Comment: In other words you want to be able to load scores from past sessions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you use [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/shelve.html). For example:

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open('score.txt')  # here you will save the score variable   
d['score'] = score            # thats all, now it is saved on disk.
d.close()
```

Next time you open your program use:

```
import shelve
d = shelve.open('score.txt')
score = d['score']  # the score is read from disk
d.close()
```

and it will be read from disk. You can use this technique to save a list of scores if you want in the same way.

Comment: i think i got it, my only problem is how do i define something with a "key" can you post a quick line or two of what the .txt file should look like?

Comment: @KevinKlute, There is nothing to define, it just works, try it out! The key name 'score' is choosen by you. I could have used `d['saved_score']`. Of course to retrieve it later you need to use the same name you used to save. The file is automatically created but it is not a text format, is a special python format to save variables.

Comment: i ran you code, except i subsituted my file name and i got the error 'db type could not be determined' sorry for being such a pain but i really just cant figure this out

Comment: got it thanks for the help, i figure out that i needed d.close

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `pickle` module to save variables to disk and then reload them.

Example:

```
import pickle

# load the previous score if it exists
try:
    with open('score.dat', 'rb') as file:
        score = pickle.load(file)
except:
    score = 0

print "High score: %d" % score

# your game code goes here
# let's say the user scores a new high-score of 10
score = 10;

# save the score
with open('score.dat', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(score, file)
```

This saves a single score to disk. The nice thing about pickle is that you can easily extend it to save multiple scores - just change `scores` to be an array instead of a single value. `pickle` will save pretty much any type of variable you throw at it.

Comment: Except pygame Surfaces. For some reason, I've had a lot of trouble pickling surfaces. not sure why...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict to hold your highscore and simply write it into a file:

```
def store_highscore_in_file(dictionary, fn = "./high.txt", top_n=0):
    """Store the dict into a file, only store top_n highest values."""
    with open(fn,"w") as f:
        for idx,(name,pts) in enumerate(sorted(dictionary.items(), key= lambda x:-x[1])):
            f.write(f"{name}:{pts}\n")
            if top_n and idx == top_n-1:
                break

def load_highscore_from_file(fn = "./high.txt"):
    """Retrieve dict from file"""
    hs = {}
    try:
        with open(fn,"r") as f:
            for line in f:
                name,_,points = line.partition(":")
                if name and points:
                    hs[name]=int(points)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}
    return hs
```

**Usage**:

```
# file does not exist
k = load_highscore_from_file()
print(k)

# add some highscores to dict
k["p"]=10
k["a"]=110
k["k"]=1110
k["l"]=1022 
print(k)

# store file, only top 3
store_highscore_in_file(k, top_n=3)

# load back into new dict
kk = load_highscore_from_file()
print(kk)
```

Output:

```
{} # no file
{'p': 10, 'a': 110, 'k': 1110, 'l': 1022} # before storing top 3 
{'k': 1110, 'l': 1022, 'a': 110} # after loading the top 3 file again
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a highscore.txt with a value zero initially.
Then use the following code:

```
hisc=open("highscore.txt","w+")
highscore=hisc.read()
highscore_in_no=int(highscore)
if current_score>highscore_in_no:
                hisc.write(str(current_score))
                highscore_in_no=current_score
                     .
                     .
#use the highscore_in_no to print the highscore.
                     .

                     .
hisc.close()
```

I could make a permanent highscore storer with this simple method, no need for shelves or pickle.

Answer (score 0):

I usually store the player names and high-scores as a list of lists (e.g. `[['Joe', 50], ['Sarah', 230], ['Carl', 120]]`), because you can sort and slice them (for example if there should be a maximum of 10 entries). You can save and load the list with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module (`json.dump` and `json.load`) or with pickle.

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter

import pygame as pg
from pygame import freetype


pg.init()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue')
FONT = freetype.Font(None, 24)


def save(highscores):
    with open('highscores.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump(highscores, file)  # Write the list to the json file.


def load():
    try:
        with open('highscores.json', 'r') as file:
            highscores = json.load(file)  # Read the json file.
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []  # Return an empty list if the file doesn't exist.
    # Sorted by the score.
    return sorted(highscores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    highscores = load()  # Load the json file.

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                return
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_s:
                    # Save the sorted the list when 's' is pressed.
                    # Append a new high-score (omitted in this example).
                    # highscores.append([name, score])
                    save(sorted(highscores, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))

        screen.fill((30, 30, 50))
        # Display the high-scores.
        for y, (hi_name, hi_score) in enumerate(highscores):
            FONT.render_to(screen, (100, y*30+40), f'{hi_name} {hi_score}', BLUE)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

The `highscores.json` file would then look like this:

```
[["Sarah", 230], ["Carl", 120], ["Joe", 50]]
```

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest:

```
def add():
input_file=open("name.txt","a")#this opens up the file 
name=input("enter your username: ")#this input asks the user to enter their username
score=input("enter your score: ")#this is another input that asks user for their score
print(name,file=input_file)
print(number,file=input_file)#it prints out the users name and is the commas and speech marks is what is also going to print before the score number is going to print
input_file.close()
```