# Want to put each element in list of lists to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a highscore list, and the order of it should determined by number of points, the second element of the lists in list. 
This is my code:

```
from typing import List, Tuple

name1 = 'John'
name2 = 'Ron'
name3 = 'Jessie'
points1 = 2
points2 = 3
points3 = 1

highscore: List[Tuple[str, int]] = []
highscore.append((name1, points1))
highscore.append((name2, points2))
highscore.append((name3, points3))

print(highscore)

sorted_by_second = sorted(highscore, key=lambda X: X[1])

highscore_list= str(sorted_by_second)
```

export list to file

```
with open('highscore.txt', 'w') as f:
for item in highscore_list:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Then it looks like this in the file:

```
 [
 (
 J
 e
 s
 s
 i
 e
 ,

 1
 )
 ,
```

But I want it to look like this in the file:

```
  Jessie 1
  John   2
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You're iterating over a string, hence over each character in that string. Just omit the string conversion and format the output in your loop properly

Comment: look up f-strings. You are using typing on one hand and python 2.7 style string formatting on the other  had - that does not fit well together : https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings   and   https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: I added a simple answer using dicts to the dupe I looked up. You find my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53684733/7505395)  and others using pickle as well

Comment: @Patrick Artner Thank you, learned something new! And I figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos on the (optional) typing declaration!

You started formatting it as a string a bit too early. Better to preserve the structure of your pairs a little longer:

```
for pair in sorted_by_second:
    f.write(f'{pair}\n')
```

Or if you prefer, break them out for more flexible [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
for name, points in sorted_by_second:
    f.write(f'{name} scored {points}.\n')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: I have a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691108/my-program-only-appends-one-user-input-to-list-when-main-is-looped-python-3 . Really appreciate if you could help me.